# No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'ShutdownDistributedTPU' with these attrs. Registered devices

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, google-cloud-tpu

I'm trying to restore Mobile-net V2 model using TensorFlow 1.7.0 version from  [this link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet), and using the following code, but I am getting an error.

```
import tensorflow as tf    
dir(tf.contrib)
tf.reset_default_graph()
v1 = tf.get_variable("v1", shape=[3])
v2 = tf.get_variable("v2", shape=[5])
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("/mobilenet_v2_1.4_224.ckpt.meta")
  saver.restore(sess, "/mobilenet_v2_1.4_224.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001")
```

I am facing the following error which is related with TPU, where as I have support upto GPU:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/home/ext_user1/tensorflow_1.2.1_cp34/lib/python3.4/site- 
>       packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1327, in _do_call
>       return fn(*args)
>       File "/home/ext_user1/tensorflow_1.2.1_cp34/lib/python3.4/site- 
>       packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1310, in _run_fn
>       self._extend_graph()
>       File "/home/ext_user1/tensorflow_1.2.1_cp34/lib/python3.4/site- 
>       packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1358, in _extend_graph
>       graph_def.SerializeToString(), status)
>       File "/home/ext_user1/tensorflow_1.2.1_cp34/lib/python3.4/site- 
>       packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 516, in **exit**
>       c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
>       tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel 
>       was registered to support Op 'ShutdownDistributedTPU' with these attrs.
>       Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
>
> [[Node: ShutdownDistributedTPU = 
>       ShutdownDistributedTPU_device="/job:tpu_worker/device:TPU_SYSTEM:0"]]

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The fix for this is to clear the preset devices from the metagraph

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("/mobilenet_v2_1.4_224.ckpt.meta", clear_devices=True)
```

The [metagraph](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/meta_graph) is used for restoring a training session from a checkpoint. For [prediction](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/4055) from this checkpoint the metagraph isn't needed. However if you want to keep training the model then importing the metagraph and clearing devices is the best way.